# Enforcing max_length on CharField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm have a CharField that has a max_length of 200 set in the model definition. I'm able to save strings of longer than 200 to an instance of this model without any error being thrown. Is there a way to enforce max_length when saving data to a CharField or is this limit only enforced on ModelForms?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show code of model.py

Comment: Here is the only line that is relevent:   heading1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: This is just a guess, thus I don't want to formulate this as an answer, but have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`? After changing your model (code) you must tell the database about it using migrations for any operation that should happen on the DB level.

Comment: Yes, I have. I think the correct answer is noted below. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it could come from your db.

> The maximum length (in characters) of the field. The max_length is enforced at the database level and in Django’s validation using MaxLengthValidator.

If you didn't add a validator, it looks like it's only checked on the db side. So maybe your db doesn't "understand" a max value, and just have a max one. Until this max, it accepts any length.

Anyway, you can control that from the application, just add to this field a `MaxLengthValidator(limit_value, message=None)`. You'll find a description [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.MaxLengthValidator).